# How to cast date inside age() in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column as date (CHARACTER VARYING) in table And it may contain dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy format dates. Now i need to convert all dates in dd/mm/yyyy ..

```
 select   c.trial_id,c.name,c.gender,age(cast(c.dob as date)) as p_age,c.relationship_name,c.relationship,c.dob,c.staff_id from mas_patient_details c
```

Even i tried doing like this

```
 select   to_char(dob::date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')from mas_patient_details
```

both of query returns

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "12/21/1989" HINT: 
>   Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "12/21/1989" SQL state:
>   22008 Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

Comment: if you store state as text of not defined format, Postgres can't guess what date you mean. Eg 01/02/1999 can be both Feb, 1st and Jan 2nd

Comment: ***Never***, *ever* store DATE values in a `varchar` column. The problem you have right now is a direct result of a bad database design

Comment: Tell your boss. He might loose a client or the entire business.

Comment: How can you possibly expect an answer if you don't know what format the date is in? How can anyone else answer this? I've voted to close because no one is magical.